# Settings.settings designer hang

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, settings.settings

After doing a source control revert on some changes I'd been making to the settings.settings designer, when reopening the designer, Visual Studio stopped responding. Now every time I open the solution, VS attempts to open the designer and hangs.

I've seen this sort of thing before, and usually VS remembers the file/project that was causing problems and doesn't load it next time you open the solution. This isn't happening now.

Anyone know how to stop VS from reopening windows in a solution? Is there a config option/command line switch/prefs file that can ask VS not to bother restoring windows when I open a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `solutionName.v11.suo` file is where this sort of thing is stored.

Deleting it fixed my problem.